# In Visual Studio 2015/2017 how does one display Angular2 Debug Console Logs/Info?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm a newbie in Angular2/4. I'm using Visual Studio. In Angular there is a Console.Log() command. Where can I see this log when I run my Application within Visual Studio Environment?

```
console.log('Log Comes here')

@Component({..)
export class App {
 s: string = "Log comes here too";

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.s)            
  }            
}
```

Comment: I Don't know if Visual studio has an integrated web browser, but if not (and you're using either Chrome or Mozilla), just press the F12 key and chose `Console`

Comment: thanks, i think that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: let me make an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know if Visual studio has an integrated web browser, but if not (and you're using either Chrome or Mozilla), just press the F12 key and chose `Console`

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017 'console.log' messages go the the Output window with 'Show output from' Debug selected, even for Angular applications, but only if you run the application under the debugger (F5).

If you start the application without debugging (CTRL+F5) the messages will not be captured.